# How to loop each document and get its data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to javascript and new into Firebase cloud functions, I want to know how to iterate each document my query returns and get from each document the deviceToken of my user, this is what I did

```
    let docRef = db.collection('user').doc(userId);
    let shopUserRef = db.collection('user').where('shop', '==', shopId);

    var orderStatusDetail;
    var notificationTitle;
    switch(orderStatus){
        case 0:
            notificationTitle = "You have a new order ! ️"
            orderStatusDetail = String("A new order has arrived, check it out")
            docRef = shopUserRef;
            break;
        case 1:
            notificationTitle = "Hey there! "
            orderStatusDetail = "✅ Your order is ready"
            break;
}

 return docRef.get().then(userDoc => {
       const deviceToken = userDoc.data().deviceToken
        const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: notificationTitle,
            body: orderStatusDetail
        }
    }
        console.log("userId:"+userId+"orderstatus:"+orderStatus+"deviceToken"+deviceToken)
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken,payload)
  });
```

So, what this code does is simple, if the case is 0  (orderStatus == 0) I need to send a notification only to the owner of the shop, thats why I use another reference to get that user device token , but here it could be more than 1 user that has that shop id so I want to iterate these documents to get each id and send them all the notificaiton of the new order.

The docRef here is just the customer who have bought a product and the notification needs to arrive to them.

But in `case 0` I need to send a notification to all shop customers ids

I want to know how to for loop here

```
return docRef.get().then(userDoc => {
   for(user in userDoc) {
    // I dont know if this is the correct for loop way to get each document data
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query

It sounds like you are looking for

```
docRef.get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```